# C# Excellibrary - how to get cell content?

Tags: c#, excellibrary

I need some quick help. 
How do I get the content of a cell using excellibrary? The documentation is very thin.

I don't really get the example code:

```
 // traverse cells
 foreach (Pair<Pair<int, int>, Cell> cell in sheet.Cells)
 {
     dgvCells[cell.Left.Right, cell.Left.Left].Value = cell.Right.Value;
 }

 // traverse rows by Index
 for (int rowIndex = sheet.Cells.FirstRowIndex; 
        rowIndex <= sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex; rowIndex++)
 {
     Row row = sheet.Cells.GetRow(rowIndex);
     for (int colIndex = row.FirstColIndex; 
        colIndex <= row.LastColIndex; colIndex++)
     {
         Cell cell = row.GetCell(colIndex);
     }
 }
```

It seems overly complex. 
I need to do something like:

```
xlInfo[0,0] = cell 1,1;
xlInfo[0,1] = cell 1,2;
xlInfo[0,2] = cell 1,3;
```

With EPPlus it would look something like this:

```
xlInfo[0,0] = sheet.Cells[1,1];
xlInfo[0,1] = sheet.Cells[1,2];
xlInfo[0,2] = sheet.Cells[1,3];
```

Is there a similar way of doing this with excellibrary? *(Disclaimer: some syntax error may occur in these example snippets, but they're just there for theory purposes.)*

EDIT:

```
xlInfo[0, 0] = Convert.ToString(sheet.Cells[1, 1]);
```

Gives me a NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).

I'm using: http://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: Do you mean Excel Interop?

Comment: instead of struggling with it, why not try using another library, http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ maybe?

Comment: In my hurry to finish this code I overlooked a simple fact. I had an error in my xlInfo[,]. Works fine. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Dont delete, add an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine after initializing the array (forgetting to initialize it brought about the error which i mistook for an error regarding ExcelLibrary).

```
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(directory + "file.xls");
Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
xlInfo = new string[sheet.Cells.LastRowIndex, 3];

xlInfo[0, 0] = Convert.ToString(sheet.Cells[1, 0]);
xlInfo[0, 1] = Convert.ToString(sheet.Cells[1, 1]);
xlInfo[0, 2] = Convert.ToString(sheet.Cells[1, 2]);
```